When we talk about the Likelihood in general ... Are we talking about a "Joint Likelihood" or "Conditional Likelihood"?
I am confused about this.
Suppose we collect some data and believe it came from a Normal Distribution. To estimate parameters (mu, sigma) of this Normal Distribution we create a Likelihood Function for MLE. But when talking about this Likelihood Function, which is correct?

Joint: The Likelihood of observing this set of data AND parameters that could have produced this data?

$$L_1(X = x_1 ... x_n, \mu, \sigma)$$

Conditional: The Likelihood of observing this set of data GIVEN a specific set of parameters?

$$L_2(X = x_1 ... x_n| \mu, \sigma)$$
I think the second statement is correct. We are interested in the likelihood of observing this set of data GIVEN some parameters ... and then estimate what these parameters were most likely to have been (relative to the collected data).
And this makes sense, because a probability distribution is describing the probability of observing the random variable between some range of values ... given (i.e. conditional) a set of pre-determined parameters:
$$P(a \leq  X \leq b | \mu, \sigma) $$
Therefore, my guess is that the Likelihood Function is inherently Conditional.
Is this reasoning correct?

Maybe it's just notation bothering me but it's usually $L_2(\mu,\sigma|X)$ as we have a function of the $(\mu,\sigma)$ for a fixed set of observed data. It's a function where we are evaluating the parameters where the result is a measure of $(\mu,\sigma)$ being the true parameter assumed that $X$ was sampled from.
